Cannot open source file "openssl\evp.h"
Having followed instructions in How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio I created a new C++ DLL project in VS 2019 and added to it a new header file:
#pragma once

#include <openssl\evp.h>
#include <openssl\hmac.h>

That throws three errors (whether with back slash or forward slash in the header file paths):

E1696 cannot open source file "openssl\evp.h"
E1696 cannot open source file "openssl\hmac.h"
C1083 Cannot open include file: 'openssl\evp.h': No such file or
directory

OpenSSL full package with include and lib directories is installed under "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64"
In the project settings:
C/C++ > Additional Include Directories = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Linker > Additional Library Directories = C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies = capi.lib;dasync.lib;ec_internal_test.lib;evp_extra_test2.lib;legacy.lib;libapps.lib;libcommon.lib;libcrypto.lib;libcrypto_static.lib;libdefault.lib;liblegacy.lib;libssl.lib;libssl_static.lib;libtestutil.lib;loader_attic.lib;openssl.lib;ossltest.lib;padlock.lib;p_minimal.lib;p_test.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

The following commands show that both include files exist:
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include>dir openssl\evp.h
Volume in drive C has no label.
Directory of C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl
24/06/04  12:26           106,573 evp.h
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include>dir openssl\hmac.h
Volume in drive C has no label.
Directory of C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl
24/06/04  12:26             2,203 hmac.h

Is this project still missing any settings?

My guess is that you applied your project setting changes to one configuration but are building with a different configuration. Other than that possibility I don't see anything wrong.

@john Negative.

Probably not the reason here, but to increase portability, always use a forward slash (/) instead of a backslash (\ ) in filenames you provide to the #include directive.

@DinkyDice OK, second try. Since your paths have spaces in them you must quote them. Add double quotes.

@john I tried adding arbitrary paths about C: drive and throwing random .h files in them. VS sees none of them, spaces or no spaces. I asked a co-worker to try my project, and it worked on his. The only difference is the version. His is 16.11.36 Enterprise. My version is 16.11.21 Community.

@DinkyDice So you are saying that your compiler is unable to include any file from anywhere on your hard drive? That's not a version issue, that's a severely broken installation. I've never heard of a problem like that before so it's hard to know what to suggest. You do occaisionally hear of weird problems caused by OneDrive or by virus checkers. I suppose file permissions might be another issue. In any case it seems your installation is severely broken for some reason I can't fathom.

Are you running your Visual Studio under a different user account, which doesn't have permissions to access those newly installed headers and libraries?

@john There are no OneDrive or virus checkers. Can file permissions be set up per application? My user account is able to open the directory/.h files in any editor. But you are right re version: IT removed VS community and pushed enterprise to my system, but still the errors persist.

I created a directory junction to "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include" under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" and the error is gone. So it is not a permission issue, it is rather the inability of the compiler to work with include files outside of the standard directory. Will deal with the linking later.

@DinkyDice This is something very strange and also new to me. Something outside of my expertise I'm afraid. Something environmental I would guess, but no idea what.

Not going to be much fun if you have to create a directory junction every time you want to use a third party library

@john Ditto that.
